# Get total count of object's elements and all children objects` elements

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have a table, `Taxonomy`, with data that looks something like the following:

```
TaxID | ParentID | Name
-----------------------------------
1     | NULL     | Animal
2     | 1        | Cat
3     | 1        | Dog
4     | 1        | Fish
5     | 3        | Poodle
6     | 3        | Golden Retriever
7     | 4        | Goldfish
```

I then have a second table, `Table2`, that has records that reference the TaxIDs in `Taxonomy`. I've labeled the foreign key column referencing `Taxonomy`, `FK_TaxID`.

```
FK_TaxID | Field2
------------------
1        | value
1        | value
1        | value
2        | value
2        | value
2        | value
3        | value
```

The resulting hierarchy looks something like the following:

```
- Parent (TaxID=1; #elements=15)
  - Child (TaxID=2; #elements=3)
  - Child (TaxID=3; #elements=8)
    - GrandChild (TaxID=6; #elements=2)
    - GrandChild (TaxID=5; #elements=0)
  - Child (TaxID=4; #elements=5)
    - GrandChild (TaxID=7; #elements=10)
```

The `#elements` is based on how many times the `TaxID` appears in `Table2`.

I have a method that takes in a Taxonomy ID, and returns the total element count for the record and its sub-children.

For example:

- If `ID` = 1, `count` should = 43.
- If `ID` = 3, `count` should = 10.
- If `ID` = 5, `count` should = 0.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
public int GetCount(int ID)
{
    List<int> childrenIDs = DbContext.Taxonomy
        .Where(x => x.ParentID == ID)
        .Select(x => x.TaxID)
        .ToList();

    List<int> grandchildrenIDs = DbContext.Taxonomy
        .Where(x => childrenIDs.Contains(x.ParentID))
        .Select(x => x.TaxID)
        .ToList();

    int count = DbContext.Table2.Count(x => x.FK_TaxID == ID
        || childrenIDs.Contains(x.FK_TaxID)
        || grandchildrenIDs.Contains(x.FK_TaxID));

    return count;
}
```

This code gets the count in three steps:

1. Sets `childrenIDs` to equal the list of records where the `ParentID` equals the given `ID`.
2. Sets `grandchildrenIDs` to equal the list of records where `childrenIDs` contains the `ParentID`.
3. Gets the count of `Table2` records where the `FK_TaxID` equals the inputted `ID`, or `childrenIDs` contains the `FK_TaxID` or `grandchildrenIDs` contains the `FK_TaxID`.

This method returns the correct results, yet it is quite slow, and seems overly complicated.

How can I simplify this method? Can I somehow get rid or one of the lists and get all the IDs in one call? Is there a more efficient way of doing this than using `Contains()` twice?

Comment: Maybe it is worth to grab all IDs from the first table and turn them into tree. Traversing a tree is a very simple operation so I think it will be quick. Here you can find an algorithm that turns flat structure of IDs to tree – [How to efficiently build a tree from a flat structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure). Seems like it is your case.

Comment: If your tree is *relatively* static, you might want to consider something like [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) which trades really slow update performance (it has to recalculate every node in the entire tree) for really fast read performance - every possible traversal of the tree is a single simple select statement, and counts can be simple arithmetic (not even a `count()` statement!).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to make the `.ToList()` call instead of keeping the IEnumerable objects returned by Select methods?

```
    public int GetCount(int ID) 
    { 
        var childrenIDs = DbContext.Taxonomy 
            .Where(x => x.ParentID == ID) 
            .Select(x => x.TaxID); 
        var grandchildrenIDs = DbContext.Taxonomy 
            .Where(x => childrenIDs.Contains(x.ParentID)) 
            .Select(x => x.TaxID); 
        var count = DbContext.Table2.Count(x => 
         x.FK_TaxID == ID ||
         childrenIDs.Contains(x.FK_TaxID) ||
        grandchildrenIDs.Contains(x.FK_TaxID)); 
        return count; 
}
```

This way, the only call to database is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something recursively like this. Note: I could not validate, may need some tweaking.

```
public int GetCount(int ID)
{
    return 
    DbContext.Taxonomy
    .Where(x => x.ParentID == ID)
    .Select(x => x.TaxID)
    .ToList()   
    .Select(x => GetCount(x))
    .Sum() + DbContext.Table2.Count(x => x.FK_TaxID == ID);
}
```